# Peacock and date palm symbolism

Tags: symbols-symbology, trees, resurrection-of-the-dead, gan-eden, birds

In episode 2 of Simon Schama's documentary 'The Story of the Jews' ('Among Believers'), he introduces the art of the Vigna Randanini catacombs.
In talking about the imagery and the connection between the concept of Gan Eden in connection to the afterlife/Messianic era, he refers to the date palm as a Jewish symbol of resurrection, and to the peacock as a symbol of creation.

Can anyone confirm this?
Whilst I know both the date palm and the peacock to have historical symbolism in various parts of Jewish culture (the latter primarily as a symbol of unity, healing, righteousness and the Jewish nation, and the latter mostly associated with inspiration, nostalgia and longing in Ashkenazi art), I've not heard of these specific associations.